# Moving casper-rw to another partition

Tags: live-usb

I'm creating a multiboot flash drive with several linux distros on it that I boot from grub2. I currently have a live Ubuntu install set up where casper-rw is on the same partition as Ubuntu live; because I have several different distros with persistence, I am using the persistent-path boot parameter to keep them separate, which is working fine.

The partition where Ubuntu is installed is a FAT32 partition, though, and I'd like to move casper-rw to a separate ext2 partition to get around the 4Gb file size limitation.  I can't figure out how to do that.  I tried doing something like persistence-path=/dev/sdb2/ubuntu (and put casper-rw in that directory), but it doesn't seem like persistence-path knows how to navigate devices (I get an error that looks like it's from overlayfs about lowerdir being invalid when I do that).

In other distros I'm able to tell it which device to put the persistence file on, and it can be separate from the device where vmlinuz lives.  Is this possible with Ubuntu?  If so, how?  Just to be clear, I DON'T want to create a casper-rw partition (since I want separate casper-rw files for each of my distros).  I just want to be able to tell grub which partition to look on for my persistence file, where that partition is different from the one where my Ubuntu system files live.

Comment: YUMI has a method that allows casper-rw files over 4GB. I believe that it creates a casper-rw file that is like a virtual ext4 partition, with the help of grub4dos. I will look through my stuff to see if I ever got it working with persistent-path. I know I never got persistent partitions working with persistent-path.

Answer (score 1):

### YUMI Multi Boot

**YUMI** will make a Multi Boot USB with multiple persistent files larger than 4GB. Persistent=path is not required.

There is a version for BIOS Boot and a Version for UEFI Boot.

For casper-rw files greater than 4GB start with a NTFS formatted drive.

If my memory is correct, the UEFI version is FAT32 only and does not work for large casper-rw files.

https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

See also: [Casper-rw files larger than 4GB - please confirm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952453/casper-rw-files-larger-than-4gb-please-confirm)

### Multi Boot Full Install USB BIOS/UEFI

Now days USB flash drives are getting large and saving room booting squash file systems and ISO's is not so important.

**Mkusb** makes a great base for custom Multi Boot USBs. The following shows how to make a Full install USB, that boots both BIOS and UEFI and then further modify it as a Multi Booter, (that even boots ISOs using grub2).

- Use **mkusb** to make a Live system on the Installer USB (2GB or larger).
- Use **mkusb** to make a Persistent system on the Target USB using default settings with >25GB persistence, (remaining NTFS partition is used as Windows accessible data partition). Select upefi to insure grub 2.02 for ISO booting.

[image]

- As soon as mkusb finishes, open GParted and delete sdx4, the ISO9660 partition and expand sdx5 into the recovered space, sdx being the device name of the Target drive.

[image]

- Unplug or remove HDD before proceeding further, (optional but highly recommended in UEFI mode).
- Boot Installer drive, select Try.
- Insert Target drive

Start Install Ubuntu...

- Select Something else.
- Select sdx5, (on the target drive), and click Change.

[image]

- Select Use as: ext4, Format and Mount point: /.

Don't touch any other partitions (unless adding a /home partition).

- Select sdx5 as **Device for boot loader installation**.
- Complete installation.
- Cut grub.cfg from sdx5/boot/grub and paste to sdx3/boot/grub, overwriting the existing grub.cfg file.
- Boot the target drive and run sudo update-grub to add all drives to boot menu.

**Multi Boot**

Multiple OS, both Full install and Live/Persistent can be added to the USB.

Create a drive as suggested above, then divide the expanded partition into parts, (sdx5, sdx6, sdx7... in this case).

You can then install Ubuntu on one partition and other OS on the other partition(s).

- Divide sdx5 into as many ext4 partitions as you have OS. Size should be about 8GB each or larger.
- Boot Live mkusb installer and insert the target drive.
- At partitioning selected "Something else".
- Choose sdx5 for /.
- Install bootloader to sdx5.
- Leave all other partition's format boxes unchecked.
- Repeat this with sdx6, sdx7, etc, and the OS's you choose to install.
- After the last install cut grub.cfg from sdx6/boot/grub and paste to sdx3/boot/grub, overwriting the existing grub.cfg file.
- Boot the flash drive and do an update-grub. This will add all the OS to grub.

**You can add a few OS ISO's if you wish:**

- Create a folder in the NTFS partition sdx1 named isos.
- Add a few ISO's.
- Edit sdx3/boot/grub adding menuentries similar to the following:

  ```
  menuentry "xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64 Partition 6" {
   set isofile="/isos/xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
   set root='(/dev/sdx,msdos2)'
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXX-XXXX
   loopback loop ($root)$isofile
   linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  }
  ```
- Substitute your sixth, (seventh and eighth), partition's UUID for XXXX-XXXX
- vmlinuz may need to be vmlinuz.efi for some versions.
- Each ISO can have it's own casper-rw and home-rw persistence files if desired, but it starts to get a little more complicated as you need to add the "persistent-path" to each menuentry.

If ISO booting is anticipated use pre 19.10 grub 2.02 as grub 2.04 is not working for booting ISO's

Comment: When I originally set this up I researched all the various multiboot tools, and for various reasons I don't think YUMI works for me.  There are a few reasons - I need both BIOS and UEFI support, not one or the other, and I have also installed various Windows preboot environments on it as well, plus installing a few full linux distros that aren't isos, etc.

The idea about using an NTFS partition is interesting though.  Are you saying that it's possible to install a live ubuntu image to an NTFS partition? I didn't think NTFS was supported well for Linux?

Comment: I have tried casper-rw on a NTFS partition using UNetbootin, MultiBootUSB and a few others, without success. (Sundar suggested MBUSB might work with NTFS >4GB, but it did not work for me). The NTFS method used by YUMI only works with BIOS boot. Rufus 3.8 allows an ext3 persistent partition > 4GB for Ubuntu 19.10, and later, both BIOS and UEFI. Rufus only allows one OS per disk. One solution that might work for you is to make Full installs to USB rather than Persistent.  If you find a solution please post your solution here, I have been interested in this subject a long time.